# KendoJs is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a code to call kendoJS library like this:

```
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("#TabStrip").kendoTabStrip({
            "animation":false
    });
});
```

When I run the code, in console I found an error like this:

[image]

When I try to add kendo library:

```
<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/kendo/2013.1.514/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/kendo/2013.1.514/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/kendoJs/2013.1.514/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/css/jquery.pnotify.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/css/jquery.jOrgChart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/css/DataTable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/css/getorgchart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/data.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/jquery.jOrgChart.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/jquery.jOrgChart3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/setting.js"></script>
```

I found an error like this:
[image]

jQuery is not defined. Why I get an error like that?. The css and javascript in different library.

Comment: you need to add jquery reference before kendo script.

Comment: i haved added the jquery. here the code `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I agree with @A.T. Kendo UI is a framework that depends of jQuery, so you first the reference to jQuery,js and next the reference to kendo.js

Comment: is it before kendo script?

Comment: Never add absolute paths in script or css reference.

Comment: @A.T. yes, i called it before kendo.js

Comment: @DinoMyte what do you mean absolute path?, sorry i am very beginner in coding

Comment: @user3505775: You should never use url like src="http://localhost/CST/...." since the server and port number would change. Use relative paths like src="/CST/....". Also check if the jquery.min.js is loaded in the browser using console.log($);

Comment: @DinoMyte oh oke, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/kendo/2013.1.514/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/kendo/2013.1.514/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


 ***<!--jquery.min.js should be before kendo.all.min.js -->***

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/kendoJs/2013.1.514/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/css/jquery.pnotify.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/css/jquery.jOrgChart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/css/DataTable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://localhost/CST/public/css/getorgchart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/data.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/jquery.jOrgChart.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/jquery.jOrgChart3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/CST/public/js/setting.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok,so your jQuery problem is solved, now move to next. Please find in which file ot is undefined and find it dependencies and move them up in order. next I must suggest you to read about js bundling on internet as this approach is outdated and look ugly.

Comment: You are right, but you miss few library. Thanks for the answers